# Generic Object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have a class declared as follows:

```
Public MustInherit Container(Of T As {New, BaseClass}) Inherits ArrayList(Of T)
```

I have classes that inherit this class.

I have another class that I must pass instances in this method:

```
Public Sub LoadCollection(Of T As {BaseClass, New})(ByRef Collection As Container(Of T))
```

I need to store the passed in object in a global variable, but i can't simply declare it:

```
Private _Container as Collection(Of BaseClass)
```

What is the syntax to declare this object?

Comment: Please don't use a global variable.  Why is it that you need a global variable for this container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry haven't got time to expand on this right now, but I think [this link](http://rasor.wordpress.com/2008/08/19/cast-a-generic-list-c/) describes your underlying problem and a solution.

(You might also find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucian/archive/2008/10/02/co-and-contra-variance-how-do-i-convert-a-list-of-apple-into-a-list-of-fruit.aspx) interesting.)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be a global variable.  Container is an idea, not a thing.

As you have it designed, that idea is only formed into an actual thing inside LoadCollection().  You need to convey the information outside of that method.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. "Collection" is a variable name, not a Type.  I think this is what you want:

```
Private _Container as Container(Of BaseClass)
```

Also, ArrayList is not a Generic class; don't you mean Inherits ***List***(of T) ?